# Looping through JSON format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop, foreach

i'm a novice trying to make a bus stop app written in javascript.

i need to build a JSON with the id of street and the street name.

i have built this json:

```
{
    "id1": "2001",
    "street1": "street name a",
    "id2": "1297",
    "street2": "street name b",
    "id3": "1347",
    "street3": "street name c",
    "id4": "3310",
    "street4": "street name d",
    "id5": "4770",
    "street5": "street name e",
    "id6": "3133",
    "street6": "street name f",
    "id7": "3230",
    "street7": "street name g",
    "id8": "1471",
    "street8": "street name h",
    "id9": "1002",
    "street9": "street name i",
    "id10": "3816",
    "street10": "street name l"
}
```

there are 10 stops to choose but only one is required.

i need to do this in pure javascript, no jQuery or other JS framework.

so i wanted to cycle this JSON to check which id is not undefined, in order to take only the id with values.

i tryed to build a simple for loop for JSON parsing searching also on Google and here but im new to JSON and all the solutions didn't suit for my needs.

Please someone teach me how to do it...meanwhile i'll study how JSON work.

Comment: So... what is the actual question here? How to 'loop through (a) json (string)'? You must have tried something...

Comment: Yes @Sumurai8 , i was in a hurry and i didn't read all the question before posting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can loop through this json object.

you can assign your json definition into a variable, and if this json definition you have to parse it using the `function JSON.parse()`

```
var data = {
    "id1": "2001",
    "street1": "street name a",
    "id2": "1297",
    "street2": "street name b",
    "id3": "1347",
    "street3": "street name c",
    "id4": "3310",
    "street4": "street name d",
    "id5": "4770",
    "street5": "street name e",
    "id6": "3133",
    "street6": "street name f",
    "id7": "3230",
    "street7": "street name g",
    "id8": "1471",
    "street8": "street name h",
    "id9": "1002",
    "street9": "street name i",
    "id10": "3816",
    "street10": "street name l"
}
```

if you know how many bus stops in this object, you can do this

```
var stops = 10;
for (var i=1;i<=stops;i++)
{
    var id = data['id'+i];  // it returns '2001' in the first iteration 
    var street = data['street'+i]; // it returns 'street name a' in the first iteration 
}
```

Here is an example on <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnozjsv7/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for helping me, @Khalid . Your solution suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine your JSON to be Array of Objects and you can loop through it with index:

```
var stops = [
    {"id": "2001",
    "street": "street name a"},
    {"id": "1297",
    "street": "street name b"}
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have an indexer in your data structure so use id instead of id1 and street instead of street1, the place of the element in the structure determines it's index. Image what would happen with an indexer in the name, five hundred bus stops and you needing to put a new bus stop at index 3 ?

so the data structure becomes something like :

```
var busstops = [
    { "id": "2001", "street": "street name a"}, 
    { "id": "1297", "street": "street name b"}, 
    { "id": "1347", "street": "street name c"},
    { "id": "3310", "street": "street name d"},
    { "id": "4770", "street": "street name e"}, 
    { "id": "3133", "street": "street name f"}, 
    { "id": "3230", "street": "street name g"}, 
    { "id": "1471", "street": "street name h"}, 
    { "id": "1002", "street": "street name i"}, 
    { "id": "3816", "street ": "street name l"}
]
```

no you can loop it:

```
var i = 0;
while (stop = busstops[i++]) {
    alert(stop.id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for teaching me that. your solution is good as Khalid's one, unfortunately i can only accept one answer!